# sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve giving "UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL."

Tags: api, salesforcedx

I'm stumped on this one. I get that the error has to do with an API version mismatch, but as far as I can see everything is on the same version.

I'm trying to pull an unmanaged package from my sandbox using `force:mdapi:retrieve`, so that I can extract the package.xml file and use it with the new `sfdx force:source:retrieve` CLI command, which was released in Winter '19.

My Sandbox API is **44.0** (highest selectable version for an Apex class in dev console).

My SFDX Project API is **44.0** ("sourceApiVersion":"44.0" in sfdx-project.json). It's a new project created today expressly to test this.

My VSCode Salesforce Extension Pack is v**44.11.0**

Here's what I got in my VSCode terminal:

```
PS P:\SpreadsConsolidation> sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -p "Spreads Consolidation" -s -u fullcopy -r ./mdpkg

Retrieving source...
ERROR:  UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL.
```

Adding the `-a 44.0` flag got the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is you CLI version (`sfdx version`)?

Comment: Have you by any chance updated CLI to a pre-release version? You can confirm it by running `sfdx plugin`.

Comment: If you're using `salesforcedx@pre-release`, then you might want [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243847). Does that help?

Comment: `sfdx version` == sfdx-cli/6.44.0-dead729fb5 (windows-x64) node-v8.9.4

Comment: `sfdx plugins` and `sfdx force --version` reveal the issue! Guess I'm on salesforcedx 45.0.9 (pre-release)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to sfdcfox and the commenters above for the solution!

in CLI terminal, `sfdx force --version` and `sfdx plugins` revealed to me that even if my VSCode extensions are v44, and my CLI version is `sfdx-cli/6.44.0-dead729fb5 (windows-x64) node-v8.9.4`... well, apparently sfdx itself (which I thought was an abstraction) has a version #, and it was 45.

**[Solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243847/can-we-specify-dx-runtime-versions-by-project) is to manually override the API version used by your project**

> After moving into a project folder, specify a version override with
>   the following command:
>
> sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=44.0 This will allow you to use the
>   newer 45.0 features in a LWC project, whilst still being able to work
>   in a 44.0 org without any errors.
>
> Make sure that, if you're playing with an advanced version of the API,
>   that you keep the salesforcedx@pre-release plugin installed until it
>   is upgraded to the latest release.